# Django - Deserializing JSONField in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've a JSONField in model, lets say `x`. I'm using DRF to save the model instance.

Serializer:-

```
class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ABC
        fields = ('x', )

    def create(self, data):
         instance = ABC.objects.create(**data)
         instance.x = {'key': 'value'}
         instance.save()
```

When I POST the data, the response returned by creating the object is correctly deserialized, ie

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'x': {
        'key': 'value'
    }
}
```

However, when I GET the data using the id, it return `x` as `str`, ie

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'x': "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
}
```

How can I properly deserialize the data back to json?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` in a new serializer field to handle the return data for JSON field.

```
class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

And in turn, you would use this Field in your `ABCSerializer`:

```
class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x = JSONSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = ABC
        fields = ('x', )
```

This should solve your problem :)

Comment: What is `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` ? Could you please help me with a suitable documentation?

Comment: the `to_internal_value` function pretty much does the following things:
        1. Dict of native values <- Dict of primitive datatypes
        2. called during data validation
        3. restore a primitive datatype into its internal python representation
            raise a serializers.ValidationError if the data is invalid

Comment: and to_representation does the opposite:
        1. Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes
        2. called when calling serializer.data
        3. convert the initial datatype into a
            primitive, serializable datatype
        """

Comment: here's the link to the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)

Comment: Why can't I use the JSONField instead? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: what Database are you using, and what version of DRF?

Comment: DB=PostgreSQL, DRF=3.7.1